# A better understanding for separation of concerns. Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am an Android developer with only 5 months of experience. I am still learning and trying to do my best.

Right now I am interested in concept of `Separation of concerns`. I do understand what it means and I am trying my best to follow it in my android development, however, I found myself a bit confused when I started learning about Clean Architecture.

I would like to show my bit of code, and if, possible, get some feedback on my implementation and its correctness when it comes to `Separation of concerns`

Code [Note: I am using MVVM in this app]:

PopularMoviesFragment:

```
class MoviesPopularFragment : Fragment() {

    private val moviesViewModel: MoviesViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val adapter = PopularMoviesRecyclerAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentMoviesPopularBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.viewModel = moviesViewModel
        binding.popularMoviesRV.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
        binding.popularMoviesRV.adapter = adapter

        moviesViewModel.popularMoviesState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { state ->
            when (state) {
                is PopularMoviesState.Content -> {
                    // TODO: Find a way to deal with this via DataBinding
                    binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                    binding.progressBarLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.pageNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    adapter.submitList(state.response.results)
                }
                is PopularMoviesState.Failure -> {
                    // TODO: Find a way to deal with this via DataBinding
                    binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                    binding.progressBarLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.pageNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    adapter.submitList(state.cachedListOfMovies)
                    showSnackbar(requireView(), getString(R.string.movies_popular_message_viewing_cached_content), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                }
            }
        })

        // TODO: Look into implementing this via DataBinding
        binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            binding.popularMoviesSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing = true
            moviesViewModel.fetchPopularMovies()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun showSnackbar(view: View, message: String, length: Int) {
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, message, length)
        snackbar.animationMode = Snackbar.ANIMATION_MODE_SLIDE
        snackbar.setAction(view.context.getString(R.string.alert_dialog_default_button_ok)) { snackbar.dismiss() }
        snackbar.show()
    }
}
```

MoviesViewModel.kt:

```
fun fetchPopularMovies(page: Int = currentPage) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = MainRepository.fetchPopularMovies(page = page)

            _popularMoviesState.value = when (result) {

                is PopularMoviesState.Loading -> PopularMoviesState.Loading
                is PopularMoviesState.Content -> {
                    //TODO: Perhaps find a way to work with pages in a better, more isolated way.
                    currentPage = result.response.page
                    PopularMoviesState.Content(result.response)
                }
                is PopularMoviesState.Failure -> {
                    PopularMoviesState.Failure(result.errorMessage, result.cachedListOfMovies)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

MainRepository.kt

```
suspend fun fetchPopularMovies(page: Int = 1) = try {
        val response = IPopularMovies.getInstance().getMovies(page = page)

        if (response.code() == 200) {
            savePopularMoviesToCache(response.body()!!.results)
            PopularMoviesState.Content(response.body()!!)
        } else {
            PopularMoviesState.Failure(response.body()!!.status_message, popularMovieDao.getMovies() ?: listOf())
        }
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
        PopularMoviesState.Failure(error.localizedMessage!!, popularMovieDao.getMovies() ?: listOf())
    }

    private suspend fun savePopularMoviesToCache(listOfMovies: List<PopularMovie>) {
        popularMovieDao.clearTable()
        popularMovieDao.addMovies(listOfMovies)
    }
```

I am mostly interested in `MainRepository` and its implementation of `fetchPopularMovies`
As you can see, this one function does not have only 1 job, in fact, it does multiple things depending on the situation it is in.

1. It fetches movies using Retrofit Interface. -> Exactly what it should do
   Then it either:
   2.1. Saves movies to cache
   or
   2.2. Gets movies from cache

Therefore it does not really do 1 thing as it should if we follow the `Separation of concerns` if I understand correctly.

Here is how I think a correct implementation could look:

1. In MainRepository, create 2 separate functions. 1 for saving movies to cache, 1 for getting movies from cache
2. In ViewModel do the same thing and create 2 separate functions. 1 for saving to cache. 1 for getting from cache
3. In Fragment, where we observe. If success -> call saveCache function in ViewModel
   if Failure -> call getCache in ViewModel

Please give me some feedback on my thought process. I would really appreciate this!

Comment: This kind of question is off topic for Stack Overflow and should be posted in Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Tenfour04 I see. Okay, I will try to ask there. Thank you

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ That’s what I did. See the link I posted.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but if the OP didn't clearly read that page and asserted the code was on-topic even if the code didn't yet work properly and posted it then it would be closed as off-topic... it happens all too often.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ This is a piece of code from a working sample of the app. No worries there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository modules handle data operations. This is data Input and Output, if you think of it this way Separation of Concern doesn't really fit because that's two Separate tasks, but if you think of the Repository as the mediator between the data and the app then that's one task and Separation of Concern makes sense.